# Solving $px^n -x + (1-p)=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm interested in solving the following equation in $[0,1]$ $$px^n - x + (1-p)=0$$

where $p \in [0,1]$ and $n \in \mathbb N -\{1,2 \} $ both constant.

To start with, we can easily see that $x=1$ is a solution and I also know there is another solution in $[0,1]$ for every $n \in \mathbb N -\{1,2 \}$ and for all $p> p_c (n)$ . I've tried using the Horner method with $(x-1)$ we get :

$$(x-1)(px^{n-1} + px^{n-2}+..+ px^2 + px+p-1)=0 $$

So we get $(px^{n-1} + px^{n-2}+..+ px^2 + px+p-1)=0 $ . Then we can do :
$$ x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}+..+ x=\frac{1-p}{p}$$

or $$\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}=\frac{1-p}{p}+1 $$

But this doesn't seem to give anything useful. Any ideas on how we can solve this?

Comment: You mean to do it numerically? An analytical solution in terms of radicals I think will collide with Abel-Ruffini pretty quick (I suspect when $n \geq 6$).

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is an analytical solution, I've seen the root somewhere, but not the way you can solve it.

Comment: You've found how to solve $y=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k$ for $x$ when $y$ is an arbitrary number in $(-\infty,1]$ and $n>2$ is arbitrary?

Comment: Come to think of it you are right, seems like it can't be solved. This equation comes from solving percolation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_theory) in a Bethe lattice (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethe_lattice). And I've read in lecture notes the second solution (for n=z-1) : $x=1- \frac{2p(z-1)-2}{p(z-1)(z-2)}$. Maybe it's wrong?

Comment: No, that's not right as you can check by just choosing numbers.

Comment: You must be right, so there should be solutions for $n=3$ since it reduces to a second order and that's how far it goes. Should I delete/ close it or there is more to be said?

Comment: @Dimitris, don't give up to early, even if there are no (known) closed form solutions, there might be someone with insights that might help you nevertheless. It's only been 40 minutes since you asked.

Comment: Looking at $P_{n-1}(x)=px^{n-1} + px^{n-2}+..+ px^2 + px+p-1$ you have $P_{n-1}(0)=p-1<0$ and $P_{n-1}(1)=np-1>0$ for $n>\frac{1}{p}$ and, [this way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), another root.

Comment: @rtybase That just proves that there is some root in $(0,1)$, it doesn't give you the value.

Comment: @Ian Yep, but it shows a dependency between $p$ and $n$. Plus $P_{n-1}'(x)\geq 0, x\in[0,1]$ making it an increasing function. OP asks about "solving the following equation in $[0,1]$"

Comment: What I was trying to say is that there are $p$'s for which $P_{n-1}(x)$ has no zeros (in fact only one zero at all in $[0,\infty)$ is possible) in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in (0,1)$ then for $n\in\mathbb{N}-\{1,2\}$ large we have $p\cdot x^n\approx 0$. We have $px^n-x+(1-p)=0$ and $p\cdot x^n\approx 0$ implies 
$$
-x+(1-p)\approx 0
$$
Then $x\approx 1-p$.

Comment: I think the interesting question is: how to derive corrections to this leading order large-n asymptotic? A related easier question is: what is the simultaneous scaling of $n,p$ such that this approximation breaks down if we send $p \to 0$ and $n \to \infty$ simultaneously in accordance with this scaling? Presumably it is $p \sim 1/n$...

Answer (score 1):

Let's write
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  f(x) = p\,x^{\,n}  - x + \left( {1 - p} \right) \hfill \cr 
  g(x) = {{f(x)} \over {x - 1}} = p{{x^{\,n}  - 1} \over {x - 1}} - 1 =  \hfill \cr 
   = p\left( {1 + x +  \cdots  + x^{\,n - 1} } \right) - 1 \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

We have that $g(x)$ is continuous, and
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  g(0) = p - 1 \le 0\quad \left| {\;p \le 1} \right. \hfill \cr 
  0 \le g(1) = n\,p - 1\quad \left| {\;1/n \le p} \right. \hfill \cr 
  0 \le g'(x) = p\left( {1 + 2x +  \cdots  + \left( {n - 1} \right)x^{\,n - 2} } \right)\quad \left| \matrix{
  \;0 \le p \hfill \cr 
  \;2 \le n \hfill \cr}  \right. \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
so that, for $1/n <p \le 1$ and $2 \le n$:
$g(0)$ is non-positive, $g(1)$ is positive, g(x) is strictly increasing in the interval,
then you will have one (and only one) real root in the interval $[0,1)$, which confirms 
what you already know.

[image: px^n_1]

As for calculating the root, I do not see any other method than to use 
[Newton- Raphson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyFDq.png) or the [secant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method) approximation, starting with $P_0,P_1$ as from the sketch.